# how can i show my list in drop down list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, drop-down-menu, collections

I have a list of objects in my program.

```
List<Table> Tables;
```

and i have a dropdown box `tableList`

I want to show this list in the dropdown box. Using

`tableList.Items.AddRange(Tables);`

gives me errors. Is this not the correct way? Please help.

Comment: If you are getting an error, then your question needs to state specifically what that error is. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're looking for `databinding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        List<Table> Tables = GetTables(); /* You should fill your list with a method */
        tableList.ValueMember = "Index";
        tableList.DisplayMember = "Name";   /* For example you have Name property that you want to show in combobox */
        tableList.DataSource = Tables;
```

I assumed your `Tables` list is filled and you have `Index` property in your `Table` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what is the property from Tables class that you wanted to display in the dropdown list. If you just pass the List dropdown box cannot understand what exactly to show. You need to specify Options, Selected Value and Index for the drop down/combbox.